# setting JAVA_HOME and finding maven version in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to run my maven project in eclipse through command prompt, however I have successfully run it in eclipse. In search for that, I found the need to set JAVA_HOME variable and find the maven version. So I did

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin


mvn --version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/bin/java  //different from above path.. Is it ok ?
```

I have this in my .bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

what's wrong here ? And how can I correct it ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set JAVA_HOME and run maven on the command line:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 mvn --version
```

If this works, it means there is a problem with your environment variable.

Most likely you forgot to `source ~/.bashrc` after adding the correct path `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` to your .bashrc.

If it doesn't work it means there is a problem with your java installation.

Answer (score 5):

You have problem with JAVA_HOME settings.

Instead of

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

Use this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

In that case mvn will use:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: Solution for that problem is listed. You are not able to work with /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/bin/java because java is not located there. Also, you can have problems with permissions, but that is another kind of problems. Could you check are you have proper permissions?

Comment: updated my post and put the content of .bashrc . permissions on what and how ?

Comment: Your .bashrc looks OK. Are you sure that you are reloaded env variables? Are JAVA_HOME points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ ?

Comment: thanks a lot Bosko. It was a great help and add-on to my knowledge..:)